# rtklib DGPS error no nav data

Tags: gps, post-processing, rtklib

I want to post-process GPS files via Differential processing (DGPS/DGNSS mode)

using rtklib (http://www.rtklib.com/).

I have rover and base observations in .rinex format.

I took FINAL satellite orbit solutions from NOAA-CDDIS archive (https://cddis.nasa.gov/Data_and_Derived_Products/GNSS/orbit_products.html) in the following format:

WWWW/igsWWWWD.sp3.Z

Using the utility rtkpost from rtklib I get the error "no nav data".

Is that a problem of the sp3 format? (sp3 is listed within the acceptable formats)

Did I download completely wrong files for the satellite orbit solutions?

Comment: If you can't get answer from here I suggest to ask from the mailing list https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/foss-gps

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue:

> RINEX NAV is always needed even with precise ephemeris and clocks.
>   It's used to recognize unhealthy satellites.

https://github.com/tomojitakasu/RTKLIB/issues/87

Answer (score 2):

The "no nav data" comes from rtkpost not having an idea where your base station is.  Check out the `Options/Positions/Base Station` settings and make sure it is set to use include the RINEX nav file, the Obs file Header, or an explicit position as desired.